# Swift: What happens to a timer in action if its referencing counter becomes zero?

Tags: swift, timer, reference

In my code, I made a timer in action,
something like this:

```
var timer:Timer? = Timer.scheduledtimer(whithTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {})
```

so the timer is valid and repeating forever.

and then I made timer nil.

```
timer = nil
```

does it repeat the block even after its referencing counter is zero?

Do I need to invalidate the timer first then timer = nil?

Solved: tested and found it repeated the block even after it went nil.
[tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvmvP.png)

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: Thanks, I just tested it and found it repeated the block even after it went nil.

Comment: @YoonsuChoi If your question has been satisfied, please vote on the answers and accept one of them.

Comment: sure thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will keep repeating.

The reference count doesn't reach 0 just because you delete your own reference. The timer is still referenced by the `NSRunLoop` onto which it's registered.

Answer (score 0):

The OS scheduler handles timers.

So, if you want to delete the timer that you made, you have to call the function that each OS provide.

(in iOS, NSTimer.invalidate())